# Terminal doesn't open window on top Mac - Atom

Tags: python-3.x, macos, terminal, atom-editor, window-management

I am currently using Atom to code in Python3 on my Mac and I have a package installed ("atom-python-run") which launches a terminal window with the command "python3 {path}" with 'path' being the current working directory with filename.py included. It opens just fine and runs perfectly, but the window doesn't open on top of my atom window but behind it instead. I have to click it every time to see the terminal window and it's really frustrating. I also hate using CMD+Tab to find it as well.

This is a bug in the package I'm using (I think) and I don't want to wait for them to fix it. Are there any methods in OS X to ALWAYS open Terminal on top of every other window? Or a third-party application? I can't find a solution to this problem anywhere online.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the scripts package and use it, the output will be written to a window in the Atom application and will be shown at completion. Go to the [Atom package page](https://atom.io/packages) and search for the word script. You should get a hit on the "script" package. Install this package by just clicking on the install button and then open Atom and the python script you wish to run. Now in Atom go to the packages menu item and from that menu select "script". You'll be given several options, choose "run script" and your script should run showing the output in a window at the bottom of the Atom window.